# How to get nunit filters at runtime?

Tags: nunit

Does anybody know how to get list of categories (provided with 'where' filter to nunit-console) at runtime?

Depending on this, I need to differently initialize the test assembly.

Is there something static like TestExecutionContext that may contain such information?

Answer (score 0):

The engine doesn't pass information on to the framework about "why" it's running a particular test... i.e. if it's running all tests or if it was selected by name or category. That's deliberately kept as something the test doesn't know about with the underlying philosophy being that tests should just run based on the data provided to them.

On some platforms, it's possible to get the command-line, which ran the test. With that info you could decode the various options and make some conclusions but it seems as if it would be easier to restructure the tests so they didn't need this information.

As a secondary reason, it would also be somewhat complicated to supply the info you want and to use it. A test may have multiple categories. Imagine a test selected because two categories matched, for example!

Is it possible that what you really want to do is to pass some parameters to your tests? There is a facility for doing that of course.

I think this is a bit of an XY problem. Depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish, the best approach is likely to be different. Can you edit to tell us what you are trying to do?

UPDATE:
Based on your comment, I gather that some of your initialization is both time-consuming and not needed unless certain tests are run.

Two approaches to this (or combine them):

1. Do less work in all your initialization (i.e. TestCase, TestCaseSource, SetUpFixture. It's generally best **not** to create your classes under test or initialize databases. Instead, simply leave strings, ints, etc., which allow the actual test to do the work IFF it is run.

2.Use a SetUpFixture in some namespace containing all the tests, which require that particular initialization. If you dont' run any tests from that namespace, then the initialization won't be done.

Of course both of the above may entail a large refactoring of your tests, but the legacy app won't have to be changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer. I got the idea. Here is what i'm trying to accomplish. We have a legacy system with 2 types of tests: regular unit tests and kind of integration tests that make db calls. Such tests are running nightly and require special database initialization. I'd like to run this initialization as a part of test assembly initialization. But since it is quite time consuming - I'd like to run it only when such test category was requsted. I know that it sounds strange, but project is legacy and huge, that doesn't allow to refactor it to get better design.

Comment: Not much room in a comment, I'll add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer again, I considered all these approaches, but as you noticed this requires quite huge refactoring and the biggest problem is that all developers going forward should follow this rule (we have around 80+devs). I now decided to do kind of "lazy" initialization using a custom attribute (derived from CategoryAttribute) that implements ITestAction. Thus, initialization will happen before the very first test execution. Not ideal, but should work. Again, thanks a lot!